# How does one pull out a table out HTML using PHP

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing

I'm currently working on a program that'll run through an HTML file and grab the contents of the tables inside--so I can turn those tables into a json format. Currently I'm having trouble getting the tables out of the HTML code. I was wondering what I was doing wrong--this is the code I am currently using. I am getting an error(posting the error off at the bottom.)

```
$data = file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\text.html');

$dom = new domDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->preserveWhitespace =false;

$tables =$dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach($rows as $rows)
{
    $cols = $rows->getElementsByTagName('td');
    echo $cols; //getting error here.
}
```

The error I'm getting is:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\parser.php:28 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\parser.php on line 28

Comment: First rule of `foreach`: don't name your value variable (the part after `as`) the same as the one you're iterating over. That way you're overwriting the original variable (`$rows` will be equal to the value from last iteration when the loop has finished).

Comment: Secondly, a tip for a good question: "I'm having trouble getting the tables" is very vague. Always describe as precisely as you can; which exact part is failing and in what way (error or undesired value).

Comment: @El_Vanja so should it be $rows as row then?

Comment: @El_Vanja I added some more clarification on to where my issue was--thank you for bringing that up.

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear. You cannot echo something that can't be turned into a string. If you just want to quickly see what you're getting, use `var_dump` or `print_r`. About the foreach, yes, `$row` will work. You can name that variable whatever you want, as long as it's not the same as any already declared variable.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks--that corrected that error, but it's not printing out the HTML portion--checking back I can see that they are stored with $tables[0]. Well, I can work with that I think.

Comment: `echo $cols;` doesn't work because `$cols` is a list of `td` elements, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need another loop of `$cols`, and then you need to get the contents of the node to echo it.

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach ($cols as $col) {
        echo $col->textContent;
    }
}
```